# FM Receiver with raspberry pi

Tags: usb, touchscreen, radio, software-recommendation, cars

I was wondering if there was any way to make a software-only radio that will use all the components included in a raspberry pi 3B+. I've been doing some research and all of the FM models that I found will use the same pins that my touch screen is using so I wouldn't be able to use those FM models. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I want the radio to look like in the end, I plan to make a car radio but one that I can use with or without my phone attached. (Won't look the same as in the photo will look a lot nicer once I configure everything)
[image]

Comment: "all of the FM models that I found" - can you give an example, it may help clarify what you want - I used to use a USB device for FM (and analog TV back in the day that was a thing)

Comment: I have been messing up with cheap cheap bare bone DIY FM receiver modules: (1) AliExpress FM receiver module
https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=SB_20210506185126&SearchText=fm+receiver+module

Comment: RTL-SDR is a USB device. It's commonly used for ADS-B but it can tune to FM radio between 88 and 108MHz.

Answer (score 1):

There is no software that can make a standard rp3 receive FM radio. However there is online "fm radio" stations/streamers that work with cellular data. By using a USB antenna or dongle though there is definitely software for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).